# argument "term" is missing, with no default ,when creating a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I want to calculate the loan outstanding at valuation date for a data set. I define a function but when I call the function its giving an error saying the fifth argument is missing(term).

Function is as follows:

```
loan_outstanding<-function(c_date,v_date,l_amt,int ,pmt,term){
  l_amt<-as.numeric(l_amt)
  freq<-12
  term_in_months<-as.numeric(term)*freq

    c_date<-as.Date(c_date,"%d/%m/%Y")
    Interest_Rate<-per_to_num(int)

  v_date<-as.Date(v_date,"%Y-%m-%d")
  date_<-numeric(500)
  date_[1]<-as.character(c_date)
  int_cal<-numeric(500)
  cap_repay<-numeric(500)
  loan_out<-numeric(500)
  loan_out[1]<-l_amt
  i<-2
  while(as.Date(date_[i-1],"%Y-%m-%d")<v_date){
    date_[i]<-as.character(AddMonths(as.Date(date_[i-1],"%Y-%m-%d"),1),"%Y-%m-%d")
    int_cal[i]<-loan_out[i-1]*((1+Interest_Rate)^(1/freq)-1)      
    cap_repay[i]<-pmt-int_cal[i]  
    loan_out[i]<-max(loan_out[i-1]-cap_repay[i],0)
    i<-i+1
    }
  val<- loan_out[i-2]
  return(val)
  }
```

The error :

```
>loan_outstanding("28/07/2011","2017-03-31",500000,7,9629.918)
 argument "term" is missing, with no default
```

Is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: You have 5 arguments specified when you try to call the function, but the function as defined has 6. The error tells you that - you haven't specified "term" and it does not have a default value set.

Comment: Thanks !!!  @thelatemail

Comment: To make it easier to see what's going on its often a good idea to name arguments after the first one or two arguments (or even all of them) 
`loan_outstanding("28/07/2011","2017-03-31",l_amt=500000,int =7,pmt=9629.918,term = ???)`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pretty solution, but I just made another variable and put it after the last one in the function definition:

```
...pmt, term, [new var]) {
```

It solved the problem for me.